# How to set/unset throbber in TinyMCE using jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to manually set throbber on TinyMCE editor using jQuery plugin. Tried like that:

`$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce().setProgressState(1);`

but no luck - Firebug says only:

`1`

and nothing happens. setContents() works just fine. How to show/hide the throbber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tinymce.editors[0].setProgressState(1);
```

works fine for me. The whole tinymce editor instance gets light grey and when performing

```
tinymce.editors[0].setProgressState(0);
```

it gets the same grey as before.

Comment: How to do this on a specific textarea?

Comment: if you got the editorid you can do:  tinymce.get(editorid).setProgressState(1);